# How to export data frame rows based on group data with specific formatting in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that includes all employee data (1000 employees, nested in 50 groups). For each group, I want R to export each group data participants in a seperate excel file (or docx if possible). The formatting should be as follows:
1- The first rows should have the group informtino (i.e.  id_group, country,
region, section), then
2- the other rows should have the participants daa (i.e. sequesnce, EmployeeName, id_emplyee)

The results should include 50 different files, each file includes all employees data including their group information (attached is an example of each file).

```
# Here is an example of the full data frame:

EmployeeName =  randomNames::randomNames(1000, ethnicity = 5 ,which.names = "last") 
id_emplyee =  sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = F)
id_group =  sample(1:50, 1000, replace = T)

cou = c("USA", "UK", "AUS", "ARM", "BEL")
country = sample(cou, 1000, replace = T)
region_ = c("n", "e", "w", "s", "m")
region = sample(region_, 1000, replace = T)

sect = c("1", "2", "3")
section = sample(sect, 1000, replace = T)

df = data.frame(EmployeeName, id_emplyee, id_group, country,
                       region, section)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but the approach below should work:

```
library(randomNames)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

df %>% 
  group_by(id_group, country, region, section) %>%
  mutate(grp_id = cur_group_id()) %>%
  # iterate over every group with walk which will have side effects only
  group_walk(~ {
    
    # create a dynamic filename: adjust to a name (and folder) of your liking
    file_name  <- paste0("filename_", first(.x$grp_id), ".xlsx")
    
    # create the group header
    header <- .x %>% 
      select(id_group, country, region, section) %>%
      slice_head(n = 1)
    
    # write the excel file containing only the group header at this point
    write.xlsx(header,
               file_name,
               startCol = 2,
               startRow = 3,
               overwrite = TRUE)
    
    # create the body
    body <- .x %>% 
      select(EmployeeName, id_emplyee) %>% 
      mutate(n = row_number(),
             .before = 1)
    
    # open the workbook that the header has just been saved to
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file_name)
    
    # write the body to the workbook (same sheet but start row is 7)
    writeData(wb,
              sheet = 1,
              x = body,
              startRow = 7)
    
    # save the combined data (header and body)
    saveWorkbook(wb,
                 file =file_name,
                 overwrite = TRUE)
    
  }, .keep = TRUE)
```

Comment: FYI I tested, and this exports several hundred files each containing a single observation of the variables `EmployeeName` and `id_employee`, not all in a given group. I dont know much about exporting to excel but assume just some slight tweaking will work

Comment: @jpsmith: Thanks for correcting my typos. With the sample data this approach doesn’t make sense, since we only have one or two employees per group. It should however work for the OPs real data.

Comment: Thanks all. Is there a way to include group information as attached in the example .png file? also the sequence of the participants? I appreciate all your assistance.

Comment: @TimTeaFan Is there a way to include the header in above the participant names? This code does not display the group info yet.

Comment: @Identicon: I updated my answer. I assumed we could use `write.xlsx` to append data to a worksheet, but to do this we need to open the workbook, write the data with `writeData` and then save the workbook with `saveWorkbook`. It should work now.